# Notifications always making sound: setSound(null) is not wroking on OS >= 8

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I am trying to group notifications and trigger sounds only for some of them using notification builder setSound() method, but it doesn't work. Each time I receive notifications it triggers the ringtone even though I call setSound(null)

This is my code:

```
    TaskStackBuilder  stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getContext());
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(getParentActivityClass());

    Intent notificationIntent = intent == null ? new Intent() : new Intent(intent);
    if (cls != null)
        notificationIntent.setClass(getContext(), cls);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    InboxStyle style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    int mapId = subGroupId + groupId;
    putGroupLine(mapId, text);
    List<String> notifLines = groupedNotificationsMap.get(mapId);
    for (int i = 0; i < notifLines.size(); i++) {
        style.addLine(notifLines.get(i));
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "default";
        String channelName = "Default";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName
                , NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        if (alert == false) {
            chan.setSound(null, null);
            chan.setVibrationPattern(null);
        }
        else {
            chan.setVibrationPattern(vibrate);
        }
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
            .setSmallIcon(getSmallIconResource())
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    int colorRes = getSmallIconColor();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mBuilder.setGroupAlertBehavior(NotificationCompat.GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY);
    }

    if (alert) {
        mBuilder.setSound(getRingtone());
        mBuilder.setVibrate( vibrate );
    }
    else {
        mBuilder.setSound(null);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(null);
    }

    Notification notif = mBuilder
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setTicker(text)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(getSmallIconResource())
            .setStyle(style
                    .setBigContentTitle(title)
            )
            .setGroup("g" + groupId)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    NotificationCompat.Builder summaryBiulder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), "default")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            //set content text to support devices running API level < 24
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(getSmallIconResource())
            //build summary info into InboxStyle template
            .setStyle(new InboxStyle()
                    .setBigContentTitle(title)
                    .setSummaryText(title))
            .setColor(colorRes)
            //specify which group this notification belongs to
            .setGroup("g" + groupId)
            //set this notification as the summary for the group
            .setGroupSummary(true)

            .setGroupAlertBehavior(NotificationCompat.GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (alert) {
        summaryBiulder.setSound(getRingtone());
        summaryBiulder.setVibrate( vibrate );
    }
    else {
        summaryBiulder.setSound(null);
        summaryBiulder.setVibrate(null);
    }


    Notification summaryNotification = summaryBiulder .build();


    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_HIGH_PRIORITY;

    notifManager.notify(subGroupId, notif);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notifManager.notify(groupId, summaryNotification);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the other answers are useful, the main issue here was that the notification channel was already created. So, as stated in the docs, the behavior of a channel cannot be changed after creation (sound and vibration in this case). Only name and description can be changed, the user has full control over the rest.

Comment: I didn't think about this way. This will be useful information when I will start a new project :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is about notification importance

importance types

- IMPORTANCE_MAX: unused
- IMPORTANCE_HIGH: shows everywhere, **makes noise**    and peeks
- IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT: shows everywhere, makes noise, but does    not visually intrude
- IMPORTANCE_LOW: shows everywhere, but is not    intrusive
- IMPORTANCE_MIN: only shows in the shade, below the fold
- IMPORTANCE_NONE: a notification with no importance; does not show in    the shade

[source](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels--cms-28616)

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet,

```
 NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName,
                                 NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
```

Try replacing

NotificationManager.**IMPORTANCE_HIGH** to NotificationManager.**IMPORTANCE_NONE**

As according to Android developer documentation,

> IMPORTANCE_HIGH
>
> Higher notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise and peeks. May use full screen intents.

So it may be making sound due to this.

Here's [the link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_HIGH) to other importance values available